# Need some examples how to use Assertstatements using TestNG in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testng

How to use  below Assert statement in Selenium Webdriver

1. Assert.AssertTrue(condition,String)
2. Assert.AssertFalse(Conditoin,String)

Please let me know when the condition is fails where the String statement is shown (Either in console/reports)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void doLogout() {
     String curTitle=driver.getTitle();
     jsExecution("rms.home.logout");       
     Assert.assertFalse(curTitle.equals(newTitle), "You've not been logged out");
}

public void stayTheSamePage(){
     String curTitle = driver.getTitle();
     String newTitle = driver.getTitle();
     Assert.assertTrue(curTitle.equals(newTitle), "You've been redirected");
}
```

Basic idea if you want something to check and you know that proper behaviour (the expected behaviour) is false in condition (e.g. you've logged in and page titles are different) so you use `Assert.AssertFalse()`.

If the expected behaviour is True in condition (e.g.page titles are the same)  use `Assert.AssertTrue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You would use asserts to assert certain behavior i.e. to assert your expected result.
Asserts would halt execution if they fail.  When an assert fails, an AssertionError would be thrown with the String as part of its trace.  This message would be available at both places i.e. console as well as testng reports.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.assertEquals("Your Test Message", driver.findElement(By.className("className")).getText());
```